# Объясните пожалуйста почему компилятор для avr выдает ошибки

Tags: c, avr-gcc

Объясните пожалуйста почему компилятор avr/gnu c compiler(встроенный в avrstudio 7) выдает следующие ошибки при компиляции[image: errors]

Вот текст программы:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000L


#define ledG PORTC=0b0000000  



#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

          int New,EncState;
          int  number; 
          int ind1,ind2; ind1=0; ind2=0; number=0;
          int x;
          int light;

   interrupt void show (int i, char ind)
    {

        DDRD=0b00111111;
        DDRB=0b00000011;
        DDRC=0b0111010;
        PORTC=0b0100000;



        switch(i)
        {
            case 0 : PORTD=0b11000011; PORTB=0b111100; break;
            case 1 : PORTD=0b11001111; PORTB=0xFF; break;
            case 2 : PORTD=0b11100111;  ledG; PORTB=0b111100; break;
            case 3 : PORTD=0b11000111;  ledG; PORTB=0b111110;  break;
            case 4 : PORTD=0b11001011;  ledG; PORTB=0xFF; break;
            case 5 : PORTD=0b11010011;  ledG;  PORTB=0b111110; break;
            case 6 : PORTD=0b11010011;  ledG; PORTB=0b111100; break;
            case 7 : PORTD=0b11000111;  PORTB=0xFF; break;
            case 8 : PORTD=0b11000011;  PORTB=0b111100;  ledG; break;
            case 9 : PORTD=0b11000011; ledG; PORTB=0b111110; break;
            default : break;
        }

        if (ind==1)
        {
            PORTC |= 1<<3;
        }
        if (ind==2)
        {
            PORTC |= 1<<4;
        }
    }            

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)  
{
                ind2=number%10;
                ind1=(number%100)/10;

                show(ind1,1);
                _delay_ms(5);
                show(ind2,2);
                _delay_ms(5);
    New=PIND & 0b11000000;
    switch(EncState)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            if(New == 192) number++;
            if(New == 0) number--;
            break;
        }

        case 0:
        {
            if(New == 128) number++;
            if(New == 64) number--;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            if(New == 0) number++;
            if(New == 192) number--;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            if(New == 1) number++;
            if(New == 2) number--;
            break;
        }
    }

    EncState = New;

    TCNT1H=0x00;
    TCNT1L=0x00;
}   


    void main()
{   
            DDRB=0b0000011; 
            DDRC=0b0111010;
            PORTB = 1<<3;
        TCCR1A=0x00;
        TCCR1B=0x0A;
        TCNT1H=0x00;
        TCNT1L=0x00;
        ICR1H=0x00;
        ICR1L=0x00;
        OCR1AH=0x03;
        OCR1AL=0xE8;
        OCR1BH=0x00;
        OCR1BL=0x00;

        TIMSK=0x10;
        sei();

    while(1)
    {           
        if (number>=60)
        {
            number=60;
        }
        if (number<=0)
        {
            number=1;
        }
   light=PIND & 0b0000100; 


    PORTC |= 1<<1; 
  _delay_ms(500);
    PORTC |= 0<<1;

   }
}
```

Ошибки компилятор выдает на следующие строки:

```
    int New,EncState;
          int  number; 
          int ind1,ind2; ind1=0; ind2=0; number=0;
          int x;
          int light;

   interrupt void show (int i, char ind)
```

Извините за отсутствие комментариев и стиля кода.

Comment: может заголовочные файлы побились?

Comment: >>`int ind1,ind2; ind1=0;`<< переменные разделяются запятыми, а не точками с запятой.... >>`interrupt void show`<< и что ты хотел сказать словом `interrupt`?

Comment: То что функция будет выполнятся в прерывании

Comment: и чем функция выполняемая в прерывании должна отличаться от обычной? (без сарказма, возможно я чего-то не знаю об avr). В любом случае с точки зрения gcc этот синтаксис не корректен...

Comment: В документации https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html  я не нашел о таком способе объявлять функции, там дается немного другой синтаксис. А `int ind1,ind2; ind1=0;` здесь все ок

Comment: С ind1,2 разобрался

Comment: разобрался - это значит, что ошибка больше не возникает?

Comment: @KoVadim, не заметил, что там имена одинаковые (ну кто это в одну строчку пишет?)... в любом случае отдельно присваивать в глобальном пространстве нельзя, а инициализировать надо при определении...

Comment: да, инициализировать так нельзя.

Comment: А как инициализировать можно?

Comment: int New,EncState;
       int  number=0; 
     int ind1=0,ind2=0;  
     int x;
       int light; - так можно?

Comment: Все - разобрался. Единственное, что беспокоит - warning на `void  show (int i, char ind)`  - no previous prototype for 'show'